# How SharePoint 2019 Version History Cache works

Tags: caching, sharepoint

Is there principal difference between the algorithm of how cashe or (anything else) works when *Version history* on Sharepoint 2019 is on\off.

Currently facing problem that files of different extensions turn into 0 kb files when i open it. How ever when *Version history* is turned off it is still alive after 500 - 1000 iterations of open-write-close. While the same cycle (on 1 or 3 or 10 turned on saved versions) turn into 0 kb after 200-300 iterations.

I tried checking file size while saving and uploading to sharepoint, cannot catch it being uploaded 0 kb. Sharepoint shows normal size of a file when it is already a zero-file. It turns into 0 kb (shp shows it) when I try to open it.

It is reasonable solution to turn the versions off. But if anybody has faced the same problem, I'd gladly like to know if there is a certain reason for this problem.